# Have 2 rows reading from the same xml data chunck

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xcode

I'm facing an issue, I have data coming from an XML file, and i want to populate the rows with this info (not a problem, done) now my issue is... I want row from index 0 and index 1 to refer to the same data chunk, instead whats happening is, row 0 is reading entry from chunk 0 of the XML file and row 1 is reading from the chunk 1 in the xml file, I could just make my rows bigger and include all the stuff I need inside a bigger row, but is there a way to do this programatically?

Image:

[image]

The red lines is whats happening when my rows read from the xml file, meaning, the green is what I want to accomplish. Suggestions?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LiveIdent";

    LiveViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    LiveMatchObject *item = [_tableDataLiveMatch objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    if ([item isKindOfClass:[LiveMatchObject class]]) {

    cell.cellHomeTeamName.text = item.homeName;
    cell.cellAwayTeamName.text = item.awayName;
    cell.cellHomeTeam.image = item.homeTeamLogo;
    cell.cellAwayTeam.image = item.awayTeamLogo;
    cell.cellHomeTeamScore.text = item.homeGoals;
    cell.cellAwayTeamScore.text = item.awayGoals;
    cell.cellDate.text = item.matchDate;
    cell.cellMatchStatus.text = item.matchMinute;

        if ([item.matchMinute isEqual: @"Finished"]) {
            cell.cellMatchStatus.text = @"Terminado";
            cell.cellMatchStatusImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"Finished"];
        }

        else if ([item.matchMinute isEqual: @"Postponed"]){
            cell.cellMatchStatus.text = @"Por Iniciar";
            cell.cellMatchStatusImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"Waiting"];
        }

        else {
            cell.cellMatchStatus.text = item.matchMinute;
            cell.cellMatchStatusImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"Live"];
        }

             }
        else {
             }

    if (indexPath.row % 2 ) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1];
        cell.cellDate.hidden = YES;
        cell.cellMatchStatusImage.hidden = YES;
        cell.cellMatchStatus.hidden = YES;


    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:235.0/255.0 green:235.0/255.0 blue:235.0/255.0 alpha:1];
        cell.cellHomeTeamName.hidden = YES;
        cell.cellHomeTeamScore.hidden = YES;
        cell.cellHomeTeam.hidden = YES;
        cell.cellAwayTeamName.hidden = YES;
        cell.cellAwayTeam.hidden = YES;
        cell.cellAwayTeamScore.hidden = YES;
        cell.cellScoreDash.hidden = YES;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
```

I've tried putting the code I wanted inside the modal definition but that didn't solve the issue at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using two separate chunks of xml because you are telling it to.  If you know there will always be two cells per xml data object then you can simply adjust this line in your code:

```
LiveMatchObject *item = [_tableDataLiveMatch objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

to

```
LiveMatchObject *item = [_tableDataLiveMatch objectAtIndex:(int)([indexPath row]/2)];
```

That will return 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, etc...  then cell 0 and cell 1 will reference xml data 0, 2 and 3 will reference xml data 1, and so on.

Comment: beautiful... that easy.. have my babies plz, ty :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the 'bigger row' approach that you mention would be the right approach.

The easy way out would be just dividing by two, or using the % operand whenever you want to update the user interface or work with the selected item, but it seems like you'd have to consistently /2 or %2 throughout your controller interface.

Also if later you want to change your design for a vertical layout or a 3-row layout (just as an example), with the 'bigger row' you would just update the layout, whereas with the %2 approach you would need to change all your code.